# iPhone 5 iOS6 GDB on iPhone binaries

Tags: ios6, jailbreak, iphone-5

I'm in the process of trying to use `gdb` to decrypt some iPhone App binaries on my iPhone 5 (iOS 6) so I can class-dump them. I'm using the gdb from the cydia.radare.org source. I ssh into my phone, cd to the Application directory (iReddit, for instance), and run `gdb iReddit`. GDB loads the binary just fine,  and from the GDB prompt, I type:

`(gdb) set sharedlibrary load-rules ".*" ".*" none`

`(gdb) set inferior-auto-start-dyld off`

`(gdb) set sharedlibrary preload-libraries off`

`(gdb) set sharedlibrary load-dyld-symbols off`

`(gdb) handle all nostop`

`(gdb) rb doModInitFunctions`

`(gdb) run`

I get:

`Starting program:/var/mobile/Applications/<hexid>/iReddit.app/iReddit`

and it just sits there. I've waited a while, but each time, it doesn't appear to be doing anything. It won't break anywhere, and I've tried setting a breakpoint at **every** function (using `rbreak .`). It won't break at any of them. I have a feeling it's not even being run. I've checked to make sure no other instances of iReddit are running. When I just try running the app from the command line, using

`./iReddit`

The same thing happens. Nothing is killed, the prompt just sits there. Any suggestions on what might be wrong and how to fix it?